# nGinx server_name with regex always being caught (ec2)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx

Have a ec2 server that has different subdomains that i wish to point to different services, trying to use the server_name to catch each but not working, always defaults to first conf (admin). In the example below I want example.com to use default.conf and admin.example.com to use admin.conf.

```
#nginx.conf

http {

    include   /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    gzip  on;
    gzip_comp_level 9;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript applicat$
    gzip_min_length  1000;
    gzip_disable     "MSIE [1-6]\.";

    underscores_in_headers on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

}


#/sites-enabled/default.conf

server {

    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

}


#/sites-enabled/admin.conf

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name ^(www\.)?admin(-dev|-sandbox|)$ *.example.com;
    #server_name admin.example.com # This is still caught by all routes

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/admin.access.log;

    location / {
            root /usr/share/admin-frontend;
            index index.html index.html;
    }

}
```

And I have setup the hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 admin.localhost
127.0.0.1 admin-dev.localhost
127.0.0.1 admin-sandbox.localhost
```

Currently if i use the public dns for ec2 (http://ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/) the admin config is triggered even though the server doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp:

```
server_name ~^(www\.)?admin(-dev|-sandbox|)\.example\.com$;
```

And I cant find *.example.com domain in your hosts file, maybe you need add them also

```
127.0.0.1 example.com admin.example.com admin-dev.example.com
```

etc

Comment: example.com was an *example* i have it setup for actual domain :)

Comment: so just try regexp with needed domain name )